# Django's Double Underscore

Tags: python, django

In Django, you can make database queries like the following:

```
Model.objects.filter(name__icontains = 'bob')
```

The question is:  how is this working 'under the cover'?  Is the double underscore a Django thing or a Python thing?  Is this just a single variable named `name__icontains`, or is it some sort of attribute-access syntax?  In the former case, how does the `filter` method parse the variable name to determine that you are searching the `Model` table for a name that *contains* somewhere the string `bob`?

Comment: As a supplement to @icktoofay, here are docs on the [django double underscore](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups), the [django queryset API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups), and the [python keyword iteration tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a Django thing, implemented with some Python things.

In Python, you can get a dictionary of the keyword arguments passed to a function or method:

```
>>> def func(*args, **kwargs):
...     print(kwargs)
>>> func(a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

From there, it can simply iterate over the dictionary keys and split them on `__`, and then interpret it however it wants. In this case, it takes the last part and interprets `icontains` as case-insensitive contains.