# How does django implement double underscore in filter?

Tags: python, django, django-models, syntax

I noticed that `Django` use double under score to define a `lookup` in `Model.objects.filter` instance.

For example:

`Room.objects.filter(width__lte = 10)`

How does it work? How can I create my own function like Django and know that `width__lte` is actually separated for `width` and `lower then or equal to 10`.

Comment: Only a guess here: but `.filter` accepts `**kwargs` and then they parse the correspnding k,v pairs, where the `k`, in this case will be the string "width__lte"

Comment: filter is using `**kwargs` that is correct. but my question is how did they parse that double score, how did they implemented that?

Comment: There are a myriad of ways. You could simply split on `"__"` and process from there. Likely, or at least I hope, they used something more sophisticated.

Comment: I am sure there many ways, I want to know how is it implemented in `Django`, I could not find it in the Django code

Comment: Search for `LOOKUP_SEP` in https://github.com/django/django/blob/60e52a047e55bc4cd5a93a8bd4d07baed27e9a22/django/db/models/query.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to answers below I found the answer to my question:

`Django` have a const `LOOKUP_SEP = '__'` then using `split` to split the param to a key value pair

Answer (score 4):

[Django 1.10 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/#writing-an-efficient-abs-lt-lookup) about custom Lookups:

> Taking a closer look at the implementation, the first required attribute is lookup_name. This allows the ORM to understand how to interpret name__ne and use NotEqual to generate the SQL. By convention, these names are always lowercase strings containing only letters, but the only hard requirement is that it must not contain the string __.

From another source:

> **Lookups:** Those are basically *“a condition in the query’s WHERE clause”*. Examples in django are `lt, gt, gte, contains` and so. To create a custom lookup, you subclass `models.Lookup`. You set the lookup_name and you implement the `.as_sql()` method. Afterwards you register it for the various Field types for which it is valid.

You may read more [here](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2015/06/03/05-lookups-transforms-expressions.html).

Also I am quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29680477/6918812):

```
from django.db.models import Lookup

class AbsoluteValueLessThan(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'lt'

    def as_sql(self, qn, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = qn.compile(self.lhs.lhs)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(qn, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params + lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s < %s AND %s > -%s' % (lhs, rhs, lhs, rhs), params

AbsoluteValue.register_lookup(AbsoluteValueLessThan)
```

> While registering, you can just use `Field.register_lookup(AbsoluteValueLessThan)` instead.

From stackoverflow itself i've got django **double underscore __** meaning. [Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7451959/6918812).

Comment: Thank you, But still I have a missing part - how did `Django` get the lookup_name after the double underscore

Comment: @OzBar-Shalom I guess that is Django functionality which tells it to go for lookup when there are double underscore found. I have added the explanation for that from django documentation. I hope this will solve your problem.